# Does my 90 day visa on arrival get extended automatically if the 180 days validity have elapsed, while I'm staying in the country?

Tags: visas, dubai, uae, visas-on-arrival

I have a passport which gives me 90 days visa on arrival (multiple entry) for UAE, valid for 6 months from the date of entry - which means that I cannot stay for more than 90 days within this 6 month period.

That's pretty clear to me. What is *not clear* is whether my visa gets extended automatically if my 6 month period has elapsed **while I'm staying** in UAE. Note that I don't exceed my total 90 days stay for the initial 6 month period.

For example, let's consider the follow scenario:

1. I stayed in UAE from 15th October 2021 to 15th November 2021 which
   is 30 days.
2. My visa is valid until 15th April, which is 6 months from my date of entry.
3. I plan on staying in UAE again from 15th March 2022 to 15th May 2022, which is 60 days
4. However, my initial 6 month period expires on 15th April, while I am still in UAE.
5. I also don't exceed my maximum of 90 days for the initial 6 month period.

Does this mean that:

1. My visa gets extended automatically for 6 more months, valid till 15th October 2022?
2. I need to exit and re-enter UAE on 15th April to get my new visa on arrival?
3. I need to pre-arrange a visit visa?

Comment: That would imply that the 6-month period is meaningless - so I guess 'No'.

Comment: Usually visa has expiry date or valid until date. What about your visa?

Comment: I would guess the visa is valid for 6 months from the date of entry (15 March), so it's only "extended" to 14 September. The first visa expires on 14 April; it's concurrent with the second visa for a little while. You shouldn't be able to have a visa lasting more than six months from your date of entry. I don't *know* what UAE do, but this is an additional option 4 after your 1-3.